# CollectionView header doesn't resize on auto rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a headerView in my CollectionView and have resized the headerView programmatically based on the text size of the Label. On rotating to landscape orientation the reusable header view doesn't resize automatically but on scrolling it resizes itself to give the intended result. 
[image: In portrait mode]
[image: In landscape mode before scrolling]

[image: In Landscape mode after scrolling]

Below is the snippet I have used to resize my header.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind{

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewHeader
        var headerString = westBeaches[indexPath.section] as NSString
        var newSize: CGSize = headerString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:headerView.headerText.font])
        headerView.frame.size.width = newSize.width + 20
        headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        headerView.headerText.text = westBeaches[indexPath.section]
        headerView.center.x = collectionView.center.x
        headerView.alpha = 0.7
        return headerView

    default:

        assert(false, "Unexpected element Kind")

    }

}
```

CollectionViewHeader is a custom class inheriting UIcollectionReusableView and contains headerText as UILabel. Is there any way to prevent the reusable view from going back to its original size when the orientation changes?

Comment: Have you tried by calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` in your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method?

Answer (score 3):

For me I had a UISearchBar as a header, and had this same problem. That is after rotation the search bar doesn't fill the CollectionView width.

I fixed it by animating the search bar's width alongside the rotation animation.

In `UIViewController`

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    // Animate searchBar too
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ [unowned self] _ in
        var frame = self.searchController.searchBar.frame
        frame.size.width = size.width
        self.searchController.searchBar.frame = frame
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update UICollectionView flow layout for orientations.

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in

    }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

    })

}
```

Comment: How do I update UICollectionReusableView size in that?

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth)
    }

Comment: Change your item size. And then update collectionview.

Comment: I believe this only resizes the cell size and not the header size…

Comment: Yes, For header you have to change size while rotation and then update uicollectionview

Comment: @Swift-Master but how to update uicollectionview? uicollectionview.reloadData seems not change any thing